# asp.net core web application (.net core) reference error

Tags: asp.net-core

I am choosing Empty template while creating a brand new asp.net core web application (.net core) as a option.

I m getting some error notification within "References" folder, but I can't see any error.

[image]

What is this and how to resolve it.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you gone to View > Error List? Looks like it might be a NuGet package restore issue

Comment: correct, Thanks!, it's resolved now